# Does an intranet site need to comply with cookie laws if it's only used internally

Tags: internet, international

I'm developing an intranet site used by employees of my company. The geographic location of an employee could be anywhere around the world but they will be accessing the intranet website using a VPN.

Do I need to comply with laws related to cookies or other geographic specific laws?

[Privacy and Electronic Communications Directive 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_and_Electronic_Communications_Directive_2002)

Comment: Would the cookies only be stored on company equipment? Could you write the agreement to cookies for this site into employment contract?

Comment: I don't think my team has the power to influence employee contracts. Yes, it would only be on company equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically most work computers and networks will contain a notice during log in that use of this system constitutes consent to [thing you want to do] so it should immunize you a good deal against what ever it is you want to do.  Since the right is on the individual user and the laws exist to protect their right against monitoring, the user must consent to any monitoring if you intend to do that.  If so, they are waving that right and thus there is no crime (since the crime is violating their privacy without warrant or conscent).  Since the person using this system doesn't have too (at least in the eyes of the law, there is no compelling force making employees work on these terminals.  The strong economic incentive of a paycheck is not a legally compelling case as plenty of legit ways to make money without computers exist.).

My office pops up a notice prior to log on that use of the systems constitutes consent to monitoring or cookies or whatever use.  Clicking an I Agree or Okay button continues the log in process and answering in the negative will set you back to the start of the login proceedure.

You should make sure this set up complies with all legal jurisdictions in which your company does buisness (if your employee is working on his vacation in a nation your company doesn't have a legal presence in, you'r not responsible if it violates their laws as they can't get you baring extradition, which most nations only do for identical crimes (if it's legal at home, but illegal over seas, then it's likely you won't be extradited.).